# Casting problem once again

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to dynamically tween some movieclips in my SWF but have problems with their dynamically created names. Here is the code

```
function slidePhoto(e:TimerEvent):void {
    i = "i3";
    movieClip = i as Object;
    Tweener.addTween(movieClip,{x:0, y:0, transition:"easeInOutQuint", time:1, onComplete:waitMe, onCompleteParams:[4000, slideOutPhoto]});
}
```

Even if I declare

```
var i:String = "i";
var movieClip:Object;
```

and then

```
movieClip = i+3;
```

this doesn't work, but if I trace movieClip I get "i3" ??? Is this casting problem or am I somewhere very very wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you realize casting i into an object doesn't turn it into a MovieClip?

Comment: I need to somehow generate sequence (i1, i2, i3, i4.....) and then pass this sequence to Tweener, but it's target property is of Object type... So I can only pass mc name or another Object...

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
function slidePhoto(e:TimerEvent):void {
    i = "i3";
    movieClip = getChildByName(i);
    Tweener.addTween(movieClip,{x:0, y:0, transition:"easeInOutQuint", time:1, onComplete:waitMe, onCompleteParams:[4000, slideOutPhoto]});
}
```

Locate getChildByName at this reference page:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html

This isn't a casting problem, you simply need to locate the DisplayObject based on the name contained in i.

Comment: When I try this and then trace movieClip I receive null as a result

Comment: Yes as Jotham and Lior said at the moment you are trying to convert a string to an object and somehow use that to reference a MovieClip which is never going to work. Jotham's solution will work. I suspect that you have not named your MovieClip. When you create a MovieClip dynamically you will need to set the name property. So myMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); myMC.name = i3. It also must be added to the display list.

Comment: Well, just after importing Tweener I defined those objects as MovieClips

import caurina.transitions.Tweener;
stop();
var i1:slika1 = new slika1();
i1.name = "i1";
var i2:slika2 = new slika2();
i2.name = "i2";
as you can see I've gave them names, but once again this doesn't work.
When I trace movieClip and typeof I get i3 and string ... String is Object type, and Tweener manual states that I need Object as target... but this doesn't work...

Comment: You need to call getChildByName() on the DisplayObjectContainer that holds your 'slika' instances - the same object on which you call "addChild(i1);" or similar.

Comment: I suggest you upload a zip of your files somewhere for us.

Comment: You might also want to read, then experiment with test files until you understand this:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000662.html